# Import image from folder in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, directory, shopify

i want to add images on my `shopify` module develop with react but i don't know how to import images. i have creat a folder and add an image in but I cant use it in my page.

I have forgotten an import or I have written bad something?

```
import { EmptyState, Layout, Page } from '@shopify/polaris';
import { ResourcePicker, TitleBar } from '@shopify/app-bridge-react';
import React from 'react';
import pdt from './images/pdt.png';

const img = '.images/pdt.png';

class Index extends React.Component {
  state = { open: false };
  render() {
    return (
      <Page>
        <TitleBar title="Dealer De Coque - Module"/>
<h1>Module DEALER</h1>
        <ResourcePicker resourceType="Product" showVariants={false} open={this.state.open} onSelection={(resources) => this.handleSelection(resources)}
          onCancel={() => this.setState({ open: false })}/>
        <Layout>
          <EmptyState heading="Ajoutez vos produits pour débuter"
            action={{
              content: 'Ajouter des produits',
              onAction: () => console.log('clicked'),
              onAction: () => this.setState({ open: true }),
            }} image={pdt} >
          <p>Vous etes seulement à quelques pas de la personnalisation de produits</p>
          <img src={images/pdt.png} alt="Logo" />;
          </EmptyState>
        </Layout>

      </Page >
    );
  }

  handleSelection = (resources) => {
    const idsFromResources = resources.selection.map((product) => product.id);
    this.setState({ open: false })
    console.log(idsFromResources)
  };
}

export default Index;
```

---

**Update from Answer:**

still does not work

maybe is my folder the problem ?

[image: Screen of the folder]

here the error on the application shopify page :

[image: Error in shopify]

Comment: Shouldn't this line ```<img src={images/pdt.png} alt="Logo" />;``` be ```<img src={pdt} alt="Logo" />;```?

Comment: @szczocik Yes, that's right.

Comment: @ThomasHg  Did you try this - `import pdt from '../images/pdt.png';`

Answer (score 2):

This is the right way of importing static assets:

```js
import VariableName from "../relative/path/to/image.png";
import pdt from '../images/pdt.png';
```

Also kindly note that you need to use `../` and not `./` because `images` folder is not in the same directory as your JavaScript file. It's in a parent directory, so you need to use `..` to move to the parent and then traverse inside `images` directory.

The imported variable `pdt` contains the full URL relative to the app for `../images/pdt.png`. You just need to change:

```js
import pdt from '../images/pdt.png';

<img src={images/pdt.png} alt="Logo" />;
```

Change it to:

```js
import pdt from '../images/pdt.png';

<img src={pdt} alt="Logo" />;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I will come back to you because I solve my problem.

I had to create a "public" folder at the root of the project and in it I put my images.

then add the line: `import Image from 'next / image'` for import them

And get them with: `<Image src =" / logo.png "alt =" me "/>`

Answer (score -1):

import the image from the folder and use it as `src` to the `<img>`

```
import pdt from './images/pdt.png';

<img src={pdt} alt="Logo" />
```

Comment: Better to add some text.

Comment: yeah, i was doing that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Looks nice now.

Comment: Please take note that the file is in a different folder from where the pdt.png image is, so start with ```"../``` and not ```"./```!